# How to download a list of all users who engage with a post on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin-api

I am new to developing (read: I use ChatGPT to help me code) but I have a lot of followers and connections on LinkedIn and I want to purge all of the connections who do not engage with my content at all (I have tens of thousands of connections).
In order to do that, I want to figure out how to use the API to get a list of everyone who has engaged with a post of mine in the last 90 days.
The docs seem to all have options for downloading the number of likes and engagements and even downloading comments, but I do not see any options for getting a list of members who engage.

I have not tried anything yet, I will admit. Just looked through the docs and searched a lot of Stack Overflow and not found this topic.